# Mapping a value to one of its subclasses

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic

I have a point and a class that extends that point with some extra behavior:

```
Point(x: Int, y: Int)
WeightedPoint(value: Double) extends Point
```

`WeightedPoint` uses the same hash and equals method as `Point`.

I can make a map of the point to itself like `Point -> WeightedPoint` and make it so that it automatically performs `p = WeightedPoint(1,2,324.0); map.put(p,p)`. Afterwards I can do `map.get(Point(1,2))` and get `WeightedPoint(1,2,324.0)` I cannot make a map of `Point -> Double` because the `WeightedPoint` needs access to its `x` and `y` coordinates as well as its value.

Does this relationship have a name? Is there a data structure or pattern that directly does this?

Comment: It's very likely that your problem domain either has a very specific solution or that you may benefit from a general purpose maths library. Perhaps WeightedPoint does not even need to be a separate abstraction.

Comment: Should WeightedPoint really subclass Point? The weight is not a property of a geometric point, it would be better to have a PointWeight class with two properties, one of type Point for the coordinates and another one of type double for the weight.